# How to override AWS S3 bucket policy within organizational unit with root account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Following AWS best practice leads to following Setup:

Root account R has one organizational unit with sub-account S

`R --> S`

Within account `S` i have created a Bucket `B_Bucket` and accidentally locked everyone out with a very restrictive policy.

Now some solutions suggest to delete the policy with root credentials.
However that does not work, always returning code 403. My guess is that the root account `R` is not the root account of organizational unit `S`.

So...how do I achieve this? How can I delete the policy/bucket, which has been created in an organizational unit subaccount?

Comment: You have two root accounts in this this situation. One for R and the other for S. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using root account for R. Afaik i don't have any root credentials for S, i've created them via the AWS Console GUI and it did not ask for a password.

Comment: If you created the bucket in S then you need to use the root credentials of S. Did you create a IAM user with administrator access and then create the bucket, or did you just use the user that you create the account with?

Comment: i have used an account of `R` which could assume a role in `S`. Anyway, you were right. Even though i never specified a password when i created the OU i was able to reset the password for the root account of `S` and generate access key and secret key to delete the policy. Thanks!